# Send User Name in URL from google sites to internal IIS page

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I send the name of the user logged on my page google sites (intranet) to another page located on the IIS server.

Example:
Matheus is logged on the intranet (google sites).
Upon entering the home page, run a script that will take the user name created in google sites. For example the variable "webspace.user.userName" or any other location.
and create a tag with the following feature:

How do I send the name of the user logged on my page google sites (intranet) to another page located on the IIS server.

Example:
Matheus is logged on the intranet (google sites).
Upon entering the home page, run a script that will take the user name created in google sites. For example the variable "webspace.user.userName" or any other location.
and create a tag with the following feature:`<a href="ip the servidor?variable="+nomeuser> access </a>`

Build the method of recovering in my IIS page URL variable:

```
queryString function (parameter) {
              var loc = location.search.substring (1 location.search.length);
              param_value var = false;
              var params = loc.split ( "&");
              for (i = 0; i <params.length; i ++) {
                  PARAM_NAME = params [i] .substring (0, params [i] .indexOf ( '='));
                  if (PARAM_NAME == parameter) {
                      param_value = params [i] .substring (params [i] .indexOf ( '=') + 1)
                  }
              }
              if (param_value) {
                  param_value return;
              }
              else {
                  return false;
              }
        }

var variable = queryString ( "variable");
```

now to build  stu link with difficulties due to software used by google sites.

code to create `<a href=""></a>`

```
<script>
var name = document.webspace.user.userName;
var url= "ip the server?variavel="+name;
$(linkdiv).innerHTML.(url);
</script>
<div id="linkdiv">
</div>
```

Anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing... You're trying to create a href that links to your server, and append a variable as a query parameter to that link. The code you posted is a bit messy, and probably doesn't work. Is the problem only the fact that your code doesn't work? Or does the problem rely elsewhere?